# JUnit test for endpoint in spring boot for oauth2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

there is an endpoint which is secured with oauth2 and it works properly when I'm testing using Postman.

I'm trying to test endpoint using junit and my test "***noToken_unauthorized***" throwing *Forbidden* Exception instead of expecting *Unauthorized* Exception

what I'm doing wrong ? Any ideas ?

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test-url")
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('testRole')")
    public ResponseEntity<?> myEndpoint(Authentication authentication) {

        Jwt principal = (Jwt) authentication.getPrincipal();
        String username = principal.getClaimAsString("preferred_username");

        return ResponseEntity.ok(Map.of(
                "username", username
        ));
    }
}

@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Transactional
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void noToken_unauthorized() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/test-url"))
                .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }
}


@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/testurl/**").hasRole("test-role")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtConverterKeycloakRoles());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need your web security conf to answer more accurately, but it could be a CSRF issue (try with the `.with(csrf())` post processor). Also, you should have a look at this article I wrote: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-oauth-testing-access-control

Comment: @ch4mp I updated my post with WebSecurity conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conf keeps sessions and CSRF protection activated. You most probably don't need sessions, and as a consequence, CSRF protection is useless.

My first thought was a CSRF issue, but as your request is a GET, this is is not your current problem. You should disable sessions and CSRF anyway to prevent issues with POST / PUT / DELETE requests. If for some reason, you want to keep sessions and CSRF, use `perform(post(...).with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf()))`

Also, you don't specify the status for unauthorized requests and there are tricky differences between empty security context (like in your JUnit test) and security context populated with `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` (like in your Postman test): give a try to `get("/test-url").with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.anonymous())` with your current conf.

Any how, I would add this to your security filter-chain configuration:

```java
// State-less session (state in access-token only)
http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

// Disable CSRF because of state-less session-management
http.csrf().disable();

// Return 401 (unauthorized) when authorization is missing or invalid
http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
    response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Basic realm=\"Restricted Content\"");
    response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
});
```

You should have the status you expect after that (and your current test without post-processor).

Other point, `@SpringBootTest` are pretty inefficient compared to `@WebMvcTest`. If your intention is to unit-test a `@Controller`, use the second with mocked dependencies.

For the coming questions, when using `MockMvc` in both `@SpringBootTest` and `@WebMvcTest`, the `Authorization` header is not evaluated. Use `@WithMockJwtAuth` from [`spring-addons-oauth2-test`](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.c4-soft.springaddons/spring-addons-oauth2-test/6.1.3) or `SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt()` MockMvc post-processor from `spring-security-test` to create a test security context populated with a `JwtAuthenticationToken` at your hand. All details in this article I wrote: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-oauth-testing-access-control.